# Single word for not inherently evil but insensitive to damage done by one's actions

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for a person who might not be inherently evil, but takes actions that *can* cause a lot of harm which the actor is insensitive to? In particular, if the person is interested in propping themselves up regardless of the negative impact to others. [Callous](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/callous) seems like the best I can come up with. Curious if there is anything better.

Example: John's constant striving for acclaim would routinely harm those around him, but due to his {desired word here}, this never affected him.

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence where the expression could  be used.

Comment: @user66974, thank you for the reminder. Done.

Comment: Is he just *oblivious*?

Comment: You could try _crassness._

Comment: There are different shades of meaning between "oblivious" which suggests genuinely failing to see, such that if you knew you might act differently, and "callous" or "crass" which suggest more willful ignorance or not caring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Indifference*** works here.

> John's constant striving for acclaim would routinely harm those around
> him, but due to his ***indifference***, this never affected him.

Lexico:

> **[indifference](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/indifference)**
> *NOUN*
> **1** Lack of interest, concern, or sympathy.
>
> ‘But behind the latest official displays of concern lie the same
> indifference for the plight of the Asian masses

Comment: I was hoping for there to be some magic word like [supererogatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supererogation#:~:text=In%20ethics%2C%20an%20act%20is,and%20from%20acts%20morally%20neutral.) for another class of acts which contains every bit of meaning I'm looking for all in one word, but I'm not sure that is going to happen. I think that 'callous indifference' does a pretty good job, though Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about [apathy](https://www.lexico.com/definition/apathy) ?

> Lack of interest, enthusiasm, or concern.